# How to stop Umbraco from displaying speech bubble?

Tags: api, umbraco

For reference, I have asked the same question on the [Our Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/37284-Displaying-our-speech-bubble-is-overidden-by-another-speech-bubble-in-AfterSave-event) forum, but thus far have received no response.

We have code running in a Document->AfterSave event which displays a speech bubble:

`((BasePage)HttpContext.Current.Handler).speechBubble(BasePage.speechBubbleIcon.error, "Error", "Problem");`

we also try

`BasePage.Current.ClientTools.ShowSpeechBubble(BasePage.speechBubbleIcon.error, "Error", "Problem");`

just in case we are calling the wrong API function for showing the speech bubble.

We do this after validating a document's property and that property is invalid, in order to inform the user that something is wrong.

The problem is that, even though the above code is executed, the Umbraco code that runs after our AfterSave code displays it's own speech bubble, the one that says "Completed" to indicate that the document has been saved. This results in our speech bubble never being displayed at all.

Can someone suggest how we can display a speech bubble that won't be overriden by Umbraco's own calling of speeh bubble please?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the speech bubble by cancelling the document publishing when your check fails.

```
     void Document_BeforePublish(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.PublishEventArgs e)
     {    
         if(!passed){
             e.Cancel = true;
             ((BasePage)HttpContext.Current.Handler).speechBubble(BasePage.speechBubbleIcon.error, "Error", "Problem");
         }
     }
```

Comment: One caveat is that the code must run in the `AfterSave` event for a Document. Also I now recall that I did try setting `e.Cancel = true` in `AfterSave` and that made no difference. Reason being, in the Umbraco code itself, after `AfterSave` is called, they do nothing with `e.Cancel` at all - it's ignored. Cheers Umbraco :)

Answer (score 1):

You can work round this by injecting your speech bubble later in the page life cycle like so

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (page != null)
{
    page.PreRenderComplete += AddAlertBubble;
}
```

And the AddAlertBubble function is just has what you already have:

```
void AddAlertBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.Current.ClientTools.ShowSpeechBubble(umbraco.BasePages.BasePage.speechBubbleIcon.error, "Error", "Problem");
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I'm no longer working on that project, so unfortunately I cannot try it out :( It looks very promising though, so thanks for that.